# Recursive rename with negate filter not working

Tags: bash, batch-rename, recursive

I want my script to recursively rename all `.mov` files to `_Proxy.mov`, **BUT** I also want it to **SKIP** any files already named `_Proxy.mov`. The below command is still renaming all `.mov` files, and is ignoring the negate function `!`.

```
find . -name '*.mov' ! -name ‘*_Proxy.mov’ -exec bash -c 'mv "$0" "${0%\.mov}_Proxy.mov"' {} \;
```

Comment: [What are curly quotes and can I use them in my code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/704762/108618)

Comment: I literally had no idea this was a thing. After replacing the curly quotes it worked!!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the curly quotes. Once replaced the code works perfectly

Comment: What is the proper command syntax that you were missing? That would make this an answer. Please keep in mind the goal of each question on this site is that you get your answer, AND that others having the same issue can find and understand and apply the answer too.